# Print the three most occurring chars in Java using streams

Tags: java, sorting, functional-programming, stream

The three characters that occurs most in a given string should be printed by using streams/lambdas (functional programming). The order of characters that occur equally often should be preserved.

My thoughts were to use a `LinkedHashMap` for counting (accumulation), and then to use a `ArrayList` for sorting the results.

I would like to know, how can my code be improved - or if everything is OK. Thanks

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CountChars {
    public static void printMostOccurring(final String s) {
        s.chars()
                .boxed()
                .reduce(new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long>(), (a, b) -> {
                    a.put(b, a.getOrDefault(b, 0L) + 1L);
                    return a;
                }, (a, b) -> {
                    a.putAll(b);
                    return a;
                })
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .reduce(new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Long>>(), (a, b) -> {
                    a.add(b);
                    return a;
                }, (a, b) -> {
                    a.addAll(b);
                    return a;
                })
                .stream()
                .sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue()))
                .limit(3)
                .forEach(me -> System.out.println((char) (int) me.getKey() + " " + me.getValue()));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Examples:
        printMostOccurring("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
        printMostOccurring("abracadabra");
        printMostOccurring("arbacadabra");
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, LinkedHashMap has an ordered stream (thus `sorted()` does a stable sort) and you can probably drop all the ArrayList stuff.

Comment: Also might want to work with code points instead chars so it won't break on characters outside the BMP that don't fit in a single `char`.

Comment: @Shawn Of course, `.sorted((a, b) -> Long.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue()))` can be used with the result of `.entrySet().stream()` (type: `Stream<Entry<Integer, Long>>`), so `ArrayList` can be saved. I didn't have seen that. Thanks.

Comment: Just for the sake of it needing to be said: the runtime performance, development cost and maintainability of the code could all be improved vastly by not using Streams. I hope that the purpose of this school assignment was to show how Streams are not always the best tool for the job.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen Yes, in terms of runtime, the costs are "horrible". But the "exercise" was to use strictly functional programming. Btw, this is not an "official" task, it's a task of mine. Might not be a real world scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You should split this up into multiple functions for reuse and testability; especially, do not force a print - near the top level should be a format.

Do not use manual string concatenation `+` and don't manually cast to a `char`. Instead, use `String.formatted` and format the character code point using `%c`.

I find the double-reduce operation difficult to understand, and I also find difficult to understand the magic around your `sorted` only needing to care about the count and relying on an implicit ordering for the original characters. When you say

> The order of characters that occur equally often should be preserved.

this is troubled, and I think you actually mean "after sorting in decreasing order of frequency, characters should be output in order of their *first appearance* in the original string".

I find it easier to understand when the actual `groupingBy(classifier, downstream)` is used, and I find it easier to understand when the comparator explicitly references the index.

### Suggested

```java
package com.stackexchange;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static class CountChars {
        private record IndexChar(int index, Integer character, long count) {
            IndexChar reduce(IndexChar other) {
                return new IndexChar(
                    Integer.min(index, other.index),
                    character,
                    count + other.count
                );
            }
        }
        
        public static Stream<IndexChar> streamMostOccurring(String s) {
            return IntStream
                .range(0, s.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> new IndexChar(i, (int)s.charAt(i), 1))
                .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                        IndexChar::character,
                        Collectors.reducing(IndexChar::reduce)
                    )
                )
                .values()
                .stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .sorted(
                    Comparator.comparing(IndexChar::count)
                        .reversed()
                        .thenComparing(IndexChar::index)
                );
        }

        public static String formatMostOccurring(String s, int limit) {
            return streamMostOccurring(s)
                .limit(limit)
                .map(
                    ix -> "%c %d%n".formatted(ix.character(), ix.count())
                )
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        }

        public static void printMostOccurring(String s, int limit) {
            System.out.println(formatMostOccurring(s, limit));
        }

        public static void printMostOccurring(String s) {
            printMostOccurring(s, 3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Examples:
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("abracadabra");
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("arbacadabra");
        /*
          8
        e 4
        o 4

        a 5
        b 2
        r 2

        a 5
        r 2
        b 2 */
    }
}
```

Or, with pre-computed stream helper objects,

```java
package com.stackexchange;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static class CountChars {
        private record IndexChar(int index, Integer character, long count) {
            IndexChar reduce(IndexChar other) {
                return new IndexChar(
                    Integer.min(index, other.index),
                    character,
                    count + other.count
                );
            }
        }

        private static final Collector<
            IndexChar, ?, Map<Integer, Optional<IndexChar>>
        > grouper = Collectors.groupingBy(
            IndexChar::character,
            Collectors.reducing(IndexChar::reduce)
        );

        private static final Comparator<IndexChar> comparator =
            Comparator.comparing(IndexChar::count)
            .reversed()
            .thenComparing(IndexChar::index);

        private static final Collector<CharSequence, ?, String>
            joiner = Collectors.joining();

        public static Stream<IndexChar> streamMostOccurring(String s) {
            return IntStream
                .range(0, s.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> new IndexChar(i, (int)s.charAt(i), 1))
                .collect(grouper)
                .values()
                .stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .sorted(comparator);
        }

        public static String formatMostOccurring(String s, int limit) {
            return streamMostOccurring(s)
                .limit(limit)
                .map(
                    ix -> "%c %d%n".formatted(ix.character(), ix.count())
                )
                .collect(joiner);
        }

        public static void printMostOccurring(String s, int limit) {
            System.out.println(formatMostOccurring(s, limit));
        }

        public static void printMostOccurring(String s) {
            printMostOccurring(s, 3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Examples:
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("abracadabra");
        CountChars.printMostOccurring("arbacadabra");
        /*
          8
        e 4
        o 4

        a 5
        b 2
        r 2

        a 5
        r 2
        b 2 */
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the case, yes. In the second case, the b must be output before the r, and vice versa in the third.

Comment: First, thank you. Now you have introduced an additional (not internal) data structure (record), and I find the `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(IndexChar::character, Collectors.reducing(IndexChar::reduce)))` part difficult to read and understand. Also, I'm not quite sure if the runtime costs have changed, e.g. if they are now lower or higher.

Comment: The record is a feature, not a bug - explicitly named members are a good thing. As for performance, if you actually cared about performance you shouldn't be using streams at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149555/discussion-between-tobias-grothe-and-reinderien).

Comment: `.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` can be shortened to `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` since Java 9.

Answer (score 2):

Just a two small things:

```
(a, b) -> {
    a.put(b, a.getOrDefault(b, 0L) + 1L);
    return a;
}
```

This lambda should use better parameter names, for example `map` and `char`.

The `put` could be replaced by [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
map.merge(char, 1L, Long::sum);
```